# Dynamic svg height according to the amount of data

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I have created an svg chart using d3.js that visualizes data from a database.
For each entry in my database a chart is drawn, but the problem is that the amount of data for each entry is different.
Some entries have hundreds of data that need to be visualized, so my chart needs to have dynamic height in order to fit them all.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

(While searching around I found questions about how to adjust the chart height on window resize, that is NOT my case.)

Comment: Could you count the number of data items and set the height accordingly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Counting the data items doesn't always help, because of the way they are visualized. Usually as the items increase, the height has to increase as well, but that's not always true.

Comment: It may not be a simple matter of data length, but you must be using something to lay out the chart or figure out how big it needs to be.  You're going to have to (a) figure out your layout on a relative or data-based scale, (b) figure out an appropriate scaling factor, based on whatever minimum size you want each element to have, (c) set the height of the svg, and then (d) draw your graph based on your pre-computed layout and scale.

Comment: You could also draw the graph and then change the size of the SVG if needed, i.e. keep track of the largest coordinate.

Comment: Thank you both. It is possible to get the coordinate of the "lowest" element. But can I use that info to change the size of the chart? I have set the width and height in the beginning.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from setting the width and height again.

Comment: I set the width and height of my svg chart at the beginning of my code. I then calculate the maximum height and I re-set the height at the end. I inspect the chart using the firefox dev tools and I see that the height is re-set. Unfortunately some data elements which should have been placed below the initial height value are not drawn. The space is empty, although they exist in the html code. P.S. It is technically impossible to know the height in advance.

Comment: That's odd.  Drawing outside an SVG, then expending it later, works fine in Firefox for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4bvCm/1/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I would like it to work for me as well, but unfortunately it doesn't happen. The elements exists in the HTML code, but they are not visible in the chart. As if the extended svg "canvas" is drawn on top of them.

Comment: Thank you both, I finally made it. It was my fault. I was reselecting the entire svg when I was resetting the height. Amelia's fiddle helped a lot.